# excel if and index formula for calling multiple values

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Temp!$E$2:$E$93,
               SMALL(IF(A$1=Temp!$B$2:$B$93,ROW(Temp!$E$2:$E$93)-2,""), 
               ROW()-2)),"")
```

I am trying to add  a formula to do vlookup for multiple values. A1 should be source value and if there is matching data in column B I would like to call column E data. Currently its giving me a blank cell. How can I fix this code to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me (simplified version).

Are you using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply the array formula?

[image]

Comment: @ajen, in case you start this on a different row, the `ROW(Temp!$E$2:$E$93)-X` needs `X` to be `1` but the `ROW()-Y` needs `Y` to be one less than the first row that your formula is on.  For example, if you put this formula into cell `H1` then `Y` would need to be 0.

Comment: You are right. I did not apply the array formula. Thanks!